# How can I manipulate this CSS so the background color matches the header?

Tags: css

I'm using a text widget, Black Studio TinyMCE, in WordPress.  For some reason, I cannot get the background color to match the background of the header (**#192E82**).  Currently, the header looks like this -- as you can see, there's a white outline surrounding the text area:

[image]

And when I Firebug the selection, Firebug shows this:

[image]

I can add whatever custom CSS I'd like to.  But I'm not sure how to do so.  I'm unsure which class I should use a **#** before, if any, or which class I should use a **.** before.  Ultimately, I'd like to make that white area around the edge to match the background color of the header.

For instance, **this** doesn't work -- in fact, nothing I've tried works!

```
#widget-wrap .textwidget {
background-color:#192E82;
}
```

Does anybody know how I can accomplish getting the white to match the header background?  Any guidance would be appreciated!

**EDIT**:  Here's a Fiddle of everything I could find:

http://jsfiddle.net/jasonpaulweber/nvkVT/

Comment: can you post a sample fiddle? it would be a lot more easy

Comment: your class .textwidget is already defined somewhere, so make a new class with the `background-color:#192E82!important` property, and apply it to the  `<div class="textwidget mynewclass" >`

Comment: Thanks for responding, Manish; I'm trying to create a fiddle ...

Comment: Can you provide a link to the WP site? if possible.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi Marc.  I just made the image header bigger (which I didn't want to do) to solve it.  But it's http://www.kelwala.com/ ... just a simple site ...

Answer (score 1):

Hard to give a precise answer with only the info included, but I would inspect one element at a time, from the `<strong>` and upwards in the hierarchy, and look for an element with either a white background-color and a padding, or a thick white border. If you do that I'm sure you'll spot it. Once you've identified it just let me know and I'll try and help you targeting it with a CSS selector.

Comment: Great with fiddle, but I don't think that one captures the situation fully. If you apply a background color to the body, you will see there is no white space/border around the text box.

Answer (score 1):

According to the fiddle, the white space is padding of the header-right element

You should set

```
#header-right {
    background-color:#192E82;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vals.  I'll retry that again!